# QT missing binary operator before token "(" Error

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QT 5.7.1 and trying to build this experimental [project](http://qradiopredict.sourceforge.net/).

But when i try to build, i get this error in qchar.h file:

```
D:/QT2/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtCore/qchar.h:333:24: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if QT_DEPRECATED_SINCE(5, 3)
```

There is only one version of QT is installed right now, and i controlled the file path of qchar.h. It is in QTCore folder. I tried google search based solutions but i could not build.

I have been googling for 2 days now, no solutions yet. I appreciate if anyone helps.

Comment: Did you try to use a different Qt version to build it? Like 5.2 ? It appears the feature you want to use is deprecated since 5.3 ? (Your experimental project even recommends Qt 4.7)

Comment: Yes i am using 5.7. It may be deprecated but isn't it supposed to compile with newer version? I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that file "signal.h" hides a file in QT include directory. I renamed the "signal.h" file to "QRPsignal.h" and solved the problem.

Also, when you rename "signal.h" file (of QRadioPredict) using QT, QT renames original include file in its own directory too. You should rename again the original file (of QT) to "signal.h".

In case anyone trying to build QRadioPredict on Windows, should keep this in mind.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Qt is a mature framework and not supposed to be disrupted like that with random header file from your project (that is why there public and private headers in Qt). The real reason is that type QChar is part of Core module which configuration was not defined. Why could not you get it working with adding QT+=core for both subdir projects is not clear.